# For <input type="file" ...> self.request.POST[name] is just a string

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

Using the GAE "helloworld" example app as a base, but changing "helloworld.py" to:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write(
            """
            <form method="post">
                UPLOAD: <input type="file" name="file_param"/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_param" value="Submit">
            </form>
            """
        )

    def post(self):
        field_storage = self.request.POST["file_param"]
        try:
            mimetype = field_storage.type
            self.response.write("Mimetype: {}".format(mimetype))
        except:
            self.response.write("No FieldStorage object, field_storage={}".format(field_storage))    

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Running this in Google Chrome on Mac OSX:

1. Click "Choose File"
2. Choose a file to upload
3. Click "Submit"

The page that comes back says:

```
No FieldStorage object, field_storage=<the name of the file I uploaded>
```

According to http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#files and examples in various posts, `self.request.POST[name]` should be a cgi.FieldStorage object. But as this example shows, `self.request.POST[name]` is a string containing the filename of the uploaded file. If it were a cgi.FieldStorage object, I would expect the program to display the mimetype of the uploaded file.

**I need the cgi.FieldStorage object so I can get the mimetype and of course the value, that is, the content of the file. What am I doing wrong?**

By the way, switching from webapp2 to webapp (using `from google.appengine.ext import webapp`) made no difference. Also, running it in Safari or Firefox, it behaved the same as in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form's `enctype` must be `multipart/form-data`. Please add it as follows (method attribute is case-insensitive):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, please consider using [blobstore upload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob), because it doesn't have size limit, you can  also [use Google Cloud Storage as a backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#using-blobstore-with-gcs), which will give you more flexibility on ACL and sharing capability.

Comment: Thanks! My sample works with that change. Q1. What was your thinking in capitalizing POST, since it works with lowercase? Q2. Why use Blobstore  in preference to a datastore BlobProperty (not clear to me from the docs)?